# ORA-39122: Unprivileged users may not perform REMAP_SCHEMA remappings

Tags: oracle11g, datapump, impdp

When I'm trying to run `impdp` command in `sqlplus`, I got below error.

```
ORA-31631: privileges are required

ORA-39122: Unprivileged users may not perform REMAP_SCHEMA remappings.
```

I have granted `IMPORT FULL DATABASE` privileged to schema which I'm trying to import. but I'm getting above error.

How could I solve this?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

more than likely, you granted:

```
grant import full database to YOURUSER;
```

instead grant:

```
grant imp_full_database to YOURUSER;
```

Comment: YOURUSER here refers to the USER of a schema which you are trying to import from, am I correct ?

Answer (score 1):

```
grant imp_full_database to YOURUSER;
```

will solve the issue , you will need to do it from a privileged DBA account or else you will get the below error

```
ORA-01919: role 'IMP_FULL_DATABASE' does not exist
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use the following code:

```
grant datapump_imp_full_database to USER;
```

Answer (score 0):

For me answers above didn't work. Only way that helped - add admin option

```
grant imp_full_database to YOURUSER with admin option;
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).