# ORA-31631: privileges are required ORA-39122: Unprivileged users may not perform REMAP_SCHEMA remappings

Tags: oracle11g

While trying to remap schema in impdp i am getting this error.
ORA-31631: privileges are required
ORA-39122: Unprivileged users may not perform REMAP_SCHEMA remappings.
Priviledges are granted to users inside sql shell.
I am executing as oracle user how to grant priviledge to it.I am executing impdp after doing **su - oracle**

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: Check this : [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14397668/ora-39122-unprivileged-users-may-not-perform-remap-schema-remappings](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14397668/ora-39122-unprivileged-users-may-not-perform-remap-schema-remappings)

Answer (score 0):

Grant imp_full_database role to the database user and then import